# Generation number in here API

Tags: here-api, geocode

Is it necessary to give the generation number in GeoCoder API? Will it take the latest generation number automatically? Even though I did not give the generation number, I am getting the output correctly. So, is the API automatically assuming the latest gen number?

Answer (score 0):

The Geocoder API documentation ([here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/backwards-compatibility.html#backwards-compatibility__api-different-generations)) on the subject does sort of state that not using the gen={n} param will result in using the latest generation of the API as stated here:

> If your application requires response output produced by an earlier
>   generation of the Geocoder API, include the appropriate generation
>   number in the request by including the request parameter gen.

But I also see how this can be confusing. In the API's [list of params](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-geocode.html), that param does not have a default, but it does have a default in the linked documentation above as "gen=0 default behavior", but what is that exactly?

Various Geocoder API examples also exclude the gen param as potential evidence it is not needed for anything other than backwards compatibility.